# Unable to test iOS in-app purchase on devices, only simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, in-app-purchase

When I retrieve details for in-app purchases, they are displayed fine on iPhone simulator but simulator doesn't allow me to complete a test purchase.  I then try it from an iOS device (tested with 4.x and 5.x) and it doesn't display any data for the in-app purchase

I know the code is fine because the simulator works fine (until purchase) and when app is submitted and becomes approved, but this in turn makes in-app test very tricky to me...

**How can I test in-app purchases on my device?**

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check and this is a classic is to see if you are logged in with another account that is not the test user. Check the device's settings.

Another thing is this and I had this problem 3 times before with 3 different devices: corrupted file system. The only solution that always works for me is to reset the device to factory firmware. This is done in iTunes. It will wipe your device and reinstall the firmware with the current iOS version. Prepare yourself for at least 50 minutes of pleasure and rage while you wait everything being wiped and reinstallad.

Don't forget to backup first and don't blame me if things get wrong...